# How to check material dialog is closed in angular 4

Tags: angular, dialog

How can I check material dialog is closed? I have to run a code when dialog closes completely. I have used `.afterClosed();` method but still in IE somehow my custom code runs before dialog closes completely.

Method which return value:

```
confirmComplete(location:string):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.dialogUtil.infoMessage(`You are currently filling this order with inverntory from ${location}.
Click "Confirm" to complete the picking process or "Cancel" to change the inventory location.`,
      `Confirmation`,
      DialogUtil.MessageStyle.Pre,
      DialogUtil.PromptStyle.ConfirmCancel
    ).afterClosed();
  }
```

Following is how I am consuming above method:

```
this.confirmComplete(this.userLocation.displayName).subscribe(ok => ok ? this.process() : this.userStore.focusLocationDropDown(true));
```

Somehow `this.userStore.focusLocationDropDown(true)` is being called before dialog closes completely and i am facing this issue in `IE11` only, its working fine in chrome.

Comment: Did you test it with other browsers?

Comment: @Phael i tested it in chrome and it works fine. but in case of IE my custom code executes while dialog is closing which is causing problems with my custom code.

Comment: Get the user agent and check if it is IE, in case it is IE then force the dialog to close before you call this.userStore.focusLocationDropDown(true).